# Most simple .bat file works with cmd.exe /C in Windows but not in WSL

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is my `foo.bat` file:

```c
if 0==0 (
set foo=abc
echo "%foo%"
)
```

##### Windows (10 Pro Build 19043)

Call it with `cmd.exe /C foo.bat`, it prints "abc".

##### WSL (2, Ubuntu-20.04)

Call it with `cmd.exe /C foo.bat` it prints "".

---

##### Things I checked

- SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion changes nothing
- cmd.exe in WSL is `/mnt/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe`
- when you remove the enclosing **if**, it works

Comment: It shouldn't work in Windows - you're setting and using a variable inside of the same set of parentheses, so you'd need to use delayed expansion (`echo "!foo!"`) for the value to display correctly. I suspect that your Windows environment already had `%foo%` set and the script is simply displaying that value.

Comment: If I change the value from "abc" to "xyz" it prints "xyz" in Windows. So the explanation of a preset env variable,  can't be right. Also, I did write, that I tried it with `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`. Finally, if I try `echo "!foo!"`, it just prints that string.

Comment: Only `setlocal EnableDElayedExpansion` won't help, you need to replace `%foo%` by `!foo!` to actually apply delayed expansion. To show the true variable value replace the `echo` statement by `set foo`. Also note that `setlocal` only works in a batch file…

Comment: Thanks. Doing both  `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and  `echo "!foo!"` makes it work now in both cases.

Comment: @aschipfl Will you post as the answer?  I was just about to start work on it when I noticed it was solved in the comments :-).  Thanks!

Comment: There is no good answer yet, why there is a disparity between WSL and Windows behaviour though.

Comment: Put `set foo=` as the very first command in your script to ensure `foo` is not defined at the beginning, then try again; you shouldn't notice any difference then…

Comment: Too late, @NotTheDr01ds, the question is meanwhile closed as a duplicate, but the linked thread fully covers this post anyway…

Comment: @user3093235 Does the following explain the difference for you?  The *first* time I run `foo.bat` in CMD (without calling a subshell), it prints "".  The *second* time (and ever after), `foo` has been defined by the first invocation and prints `"abc"`.  When you launch from WSL, *every* CMD invocation results in a fresh CMD instance, so `foo` is *always* undefined.  As aschipfl said, if you ran `foo.bat` even once in the parent CMD, then `cmd.exe /C foo.bat` is going to propagate `foo` to the subprocess.

Comment: Yes I can see now, how I could have messed that up. I assumed foo to be only defined locally (non-persistently). I don't write .bat scripts very often... Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: @user3093235 Glad we got it sorted out!  And no worries - I haven't done much CMD scripting in a couple of decades either.  It really seems to be the difference in variable scope -- CMD assumes variables are exported unless defined `SETLOCAL`, while Linux shells assume they are local unless `export`ed.  Even so, a Linux process in WSL doesn't (by default) pass exported environment variables to a Windows process (such as CMD), nor does it inherit environment variables when called from a Windows process.  Exception -- This can be overcome using `WSLENV`.